# Read files from Website and load them into object without downloading the file

Tags: java, stream, apache-poi, ms-office

I am trying to read a file from a website by loading the file present in the website directly into the object (Example: if there is a PDF file in the site, I am loading it directly into PdfBox Object). Likewise, I am trying for MS Office files using Apache POI, but it throws the exceptions (java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source and Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream). Any suggestion to solve the above issue or any other way to achieve my requirement will be helpful.

```
        String docx = "http://support.skillscommons.org/documentation/SkillsCommons-Accessibility-Checkpoints-Guide.docx";
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(docx).openStream());
        if(in != null) {
             XWPFDocument wDoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(in));
                if(wDoc != null) {
                    System.out.println(wDoc.getParagraphs().size());
                }
            System.out.println(input);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit; please add also what POI version you are using, hopefully 4.1.1.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - I changed to the mentioned version and its throwing a new exception. java.io.IOException: Truncated ZIP file
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.readDeflated(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:560)
 at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.read(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:458)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.read(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:80)

Comment: Are you using maven or using the jars directly? Because some dependent libraries have changed.